# Text overflowing to left side

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

Can any one help with this? I don't want the text to overflow to the left side. I need the `<p>` to automatically add line breaks.

Here is the CSS:

```
article {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 1px 0px;
    border: 2px solid #4afbd9;
    float: left;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<article id="the_article">
  <h1>Hello guys </h1>
    <p>wefeasdfasdfasdfaewgewtawerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrfgrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrdgdsffgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfggsdfgsdfgsdfsdfgsdfgsdfggsdfgsdfgsdfrrrrrrdg</p>
</article>
```

[image: This is what ap]

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `word-wrap: break-word` to the parent element (`<article>` in your example)

```css
article {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

p {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>wefeasdfasdfasdfaewgewtawerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrfgrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrdgdsffgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfggsdfgsdfgsdfsdfgsdfgsdfggsdfgsdfgsdfrrrrrrdg</p>
</article>
```

Some documentation about `word-wrap`:

- [Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

Comment: Wow! Thanks! It really helped!

Comment: Please don't refer to w3schools

Comment: Removed.. Why shouldn't we refer to W3school?

Comment: @REVENTONMC I was wandering through the questions I answered and noticed that this question doesn't have an accepted answer, if you found that one of this answers helped you please accept it to help future users that might stumble across your question with a similar problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add a word-wrap css property to the article in css.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can either use [`word-wrap:break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) or [`word-break:break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

```css
article {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #4afbd9;
  float: left;
  width:100px;
}
article:first-of-type {
  word-wrap: break-word
}
article:last-of-type {
  word-break: break-all
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>wefeasdfasdfasdfaewgewtawerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrfgrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrdgdsffgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfggsdfgsdfgsdfsdfgsdfgsdfggsdfgsdfgsdfrrrrrrdg</p>
</article>
<article>
  <p>wefeasdfasdfasdfaewgewtawerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrfgrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrdgdsffgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfggsdfgsdfgsdfsdfgsdfgsdfggsdfgsdfgsdfrrrrrrdg</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks! :) i guess i can use either one!